# Вынести легенду за пределы графика

Tags: python, matplotlib

У меня получается достаточно объемный график, и легенда банально не помещается. Хочется вынести ее за пределы, но получается какая-то ерунда: выдает ошибку

строка 22, in ('До', [v[0]]), TypeError: объект' GlyphRenderer ' не является подписным

Я новичок, не судите строго за тупой вопрос.

```
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import PiYG
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap
from bokeh.models import Legend
 
 
output_file("bar_colormapped.html")
 
names = [' До', ' Ре', ' Ми', 'Фа', ' Соль', 'Ля', ' Си', ' Диез', 'Бемоль']
counts = [28, 25, 17, 14, 15, 23, 27, 35, 39]
 
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(names=names, counts=counts))
 
pal = PiYG[9]
p = figure(x_range=names, plot_height=250, toolbar_location='left', title="Распределение")
assert isinstance(p.vbar, object)
v = p.vbar(x='names', top='counts', width=0.6, source=source, line_color='white', fill_color=factor_cmap('names', palette=pal, factors=names))
 
legend = Legend(items=[
    ('До',  [v[0]]),
    (' Ре',   [v[1]]),
    ( 'Ми',   [v[2]]),
    ('Фа',   [v[3]]),
    (' Соль',   [v[4]]),
    ( ' Ля',   [v[5]]),
    ( ' Си',   [v[6]]),
    ( ' Диез',   [v[7]]),
    (' Бемоль'  [v[8]]),
], location=(0, -30))
 
p.add_layout(legend, 'right')
show(p)
```

И еще: можно ли как-то зациклить палитру боке? У меня палитра на 9 цветов, к примеру, а столбцов 18: можно ли сделать так, чтобы каждые следующие 9 колонок окрашивались в цвета палитры? А то сейчас 9 в цвета палитры, а оставшиеся- в nan_color

Comment: В переменной `v` у вас этот самый `GlyphRenderer` который ругается, что не поддерживает индексирование. А что вы хотели от него получить?

Comment: А как лучше удобнее вывести легенду за пределы графика?

Comment: Поиском такой пример находит: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38146264/8324991